# How can I give input to my computer from my phone?

Tags: python, android, windows, notifications

I am trying to create a python program that takes input of what homework assignments I have and stores all of that information so that I can send a notification to my phone when assignments are coming up. I want to be able to give input from my phone throughout the day and cant seem to find a way to interact with my script on my computer from my phone. Any ideas? Ps: if you know a way that I can send notifications to my phone that would also be cool.

Comment: I'd look into whether [Google AppSheet](https://cloud.google.com/appsheet) or [MIT App Inventor](https://appinventor.mit.edu/) can do this. App Inventor might need an extension to access a cloud Firebase service.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should create a classic client/server architecture. This is quite a big task. Your program running on your Windows computer acts as a server waiting for client (mobile application) requests. I propose to create a widely used REST API service using e.g. the `Flask` framework (server side) and use the `Retrofit` framework for the Android application.
Remember that when using the application on the Internet, you will have to ensure the availability of the server.
To send notifications from the server to the app, use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging)

Comment: Would this cost CPU speed to have something running in the background?

Comment: Every process costs CPU cycles. However in your case it should not be big cost, because the server will be mostly idle (in case if it is a demo project with limited amount of users).